# How to prevent Netflix from showing preview trailers on the overview?

Tags: netflix

Currently, whenever I look at the Netflix overview, it shows me trailers in the top of the page.

Also further down the page, between the category scrollers.

I find them disturbing and annoying, also sometimes they contain spoilers which I don't like.

Is there a way to disable them?
Alternatively, is there a way to inject some JavaScript (maybe using a Chrome extension?), to hide them on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such tasks as removing stuff from sites, you can use Adblock Plus' future called **Block element** and then just select the exact element which you want to kill.

[image: 0]

If **[Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus-free-ad-bloc/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb)** can't be used there is **[this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/click-to-remove-element/jcgpghgjhhahcefnfpbncdmhhddedhnk)** which does the same.

Comment: That's a really good idea, I hadn't thought of that. Unfortunately it doesn't work on Netflix, too much random in the source path. When I try to block the top video, it shows this URI `||occ-0-713-768.1.nflxso.net/art/1ecc6/db8a0a4c9ba3de480fd3a6208a2d49136881ecc6.webp` - and blocking it has no visible effect :-/

Comment: I stand corrected. It does work, it just has to be done correctly. I will add an answer with full details, because I can't do it properly in the comments, but I will accept your answer since you lead me in the right direction. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

[[Source]](https://www.reddit.com/r/netflix/comments/80jhsy/you_can_easily_disable_the_autoplay_trailers_on)

**ublock**

1. Left-click on the ublock icon in the top right of your browser.
2. Click the "3 sliders" icon below the big blue power button.
3. Copy & paste this into a new line of the text area that appears:

   > www.netflix.com##.billboard-row
4. click apply changes.
5. All future visits to Netflix will not have the autoplay video at the top of the page.

*-or-*

**AdBlock Plus**

1. Left-click on the AdBlock Plus icon in the top right of your browser.
2. click "Options" icon in the popout menu.
3. Select the "Advanced" tab.
4. Click "Edit filters" at the bottom.
5. Copy & paste this into the bottom of filters text box:

   > www.netflix.com##.billboard-row
6. Click "Add filter"
7. All future visits to Netflix will not have the autoplay video at the top of the page.

**Bonus**
To get rid of the preview trailers in between the category rows, add this as well:

> www.netflix.com##.bigRow

Answer (score 1):

Netflix finally added a feature to remove this thing.

- Sign in to Netflix from a web browser.
- Select Manage Profiles from the menu.
- Select the profile you'd like to update.
- Check or uncheck the option to Autoplay previews while browsing on all devices, and Autoplay next episode in a series on all devices.

It seems like it's cached on some devices, so after you update this setting it can still take a while to update. Mine updated after I turned my device off/on after about 5 minutes of being annoyed.